# web2py dal howto define model at runtime

Tags: mysql, postgresql, web2py

I am a newbie to wewb2py,is it possible to create at runtime a model of a legacy database, for using DAL with it? I saw that there are some scripts that create the model file, but I do not know whether it is correct to put this file in the model directory of my application, I think not, I did some experiments, I can connect to the database with DAL querying its tables and for every table I can get the definition of the fields, the I tried to define the table with define_table,it works but try to create the table on the database and return an error because the table already exists; this is the relevant part of my code:

```
conn_string = "mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}".format(user,pwd,host,db_name)
```

db = DAL(conn_string)

```
db.define_table('test1',Field('prova','string'))
```

it works only the first time, when  the table test1 does not exist yet on the database, I do not need to create the tables only work with their data, can you put me on the right way?

Answer (score 1):

```
db = DAL(conn_string, migrate_enabled=False)
```

The above will prevent web2py from doing any migrations, including attempting to create any tables.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what doesn't work and what errors you are seeing. You can start from scratch by deleting the *.table files from the app's /databases folder, and make sure migrate_enabled=False if you don't want any migrations.

Comment: Isn't it migrate=False?

Comment: If you add `migrate=False` in the call to `DAL()`, that simply sets the default value of the "migrate" argument in each call to `.define_table()`. Any explicit setting of the "migrate" arguments will override that default. Setting `DAL(..., migrate_enabled=False)` completely disables migrations, regardless of the values of the "migrate" arguments in each `.define_table()`.